# ConstraintLayout: minWidth and Ellipsize problem

Tags: android, textview, android-constraintlayout

I have two TextViews constrained to each other. The TextView with id "list..._label" needs to behave like this -> Have a minWidth when TextView with id "list..._value" is so wide that it truncates label and also makes label ellipsize. Right now minWidth is not working on label, it gets ellipsized but minWidth does not work.

Also TextView with id "list..._value" needs to be ellipsized when Label has reached its minWidth.

How can this be achieved and what could be the issue?

*Note: These two TextViews are custom but have been made more generic in their naming.*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
style="@style/Content"
android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector_white">

<include layout="@layout/guidelines" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_one_line_with_icon_icon"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/list_item_icon_size_large"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_icon_size_large"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/du_margin_default"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/du_margin_default"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/du_margin_default"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_description"
    android:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:background="@drawable/x_circle_food" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_one_line_with_icon_label"
    style="@style/ConstrainedView.WrappedHeight"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/du_margin_default"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/du_margin_default_half"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/du_margin_default_half"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/du_margin_default"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:minWidth="@dimen/du_list_item_label_min_width"
    android:textColor="@color/du_brown_wcag"
    android:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/list_item_one_line_with_icon_value"
    android:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/list_item_one_line_with_icon_icon"
    android:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_goneMarginRight="@dimen/du_margin_default_half"
    android:typography="@style/L4"
    tools:text="Type something"
    tools:visibility="visible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@id/list_item_one_line_with_icon_value"
    style="@style/Wrapped"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/du_margin_default"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/du_margin_default_half"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/du_margin_default"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textColor="@color/du_black"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/list_item_one_line_with_icon_arrow"
    android:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
    android:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/list_item_one_line_with_icon_label"
    android:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_goneMarginRight="@dimen/du_margin_default_half"
    android:typography="@style/L3"
    tools:text="-2 5000,00"
    tools:visibility="visible" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@id/list_item_one_line_with_icon_arrow"
    style="@style/ConstrainedView"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/list_item_arrow_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_arrow_height"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_description"
    android:scaleType="fitEnd"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_right_arrow_soft_brown"
    android:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guidelines_end"
    android:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:visibility="visible" />
```

STYLES

```
<style name="ConstrainedView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
</style>

<style name="Wrapped">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>

<style name="ConstrainedView.WrappedHeight">
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Could you paste styles of these textViews?

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky I have included styles now :)

Comment: I'm not really able to understand what you're trying to achieve, could you post an example of your expected behaviour? I guess you want to achieve something like  "[Label][...text truncated by ellipsize]" where the [] blocks symbolize the TextViews.

Comment: @SebRut I want label to be ellipsized but still have a minWidth. Like so -> [La...][LooongValue]. Also if value gets so big so there is no more space then it too should get ellipsized. Like so -> [La...][LooooongVal...]. However label must me ellipsized first. Does that make sense?

Comment: Could you post code of the *guidelines*?